How to determine the limits of single integrals in converting a double integral with variable limits
I have a problem to understand the following simplification for gravitational potential:
$\phi(r)=\int_r^\infty (-4\pi G dr/r^2) (\int_0^r\rho r^2 dr)\tag1$
$\phi(r)=-4\pi G [\frac{1}{r}(\int_0^r \rho r^2 dr)+\int_r^\infty \rho r dr]\tag2$
As you see two different bounds in integrals above. I tried to convert Eq.(1) to Eq.(2)  by using method of "integration by parts" as (assuming $4\pi G=1$):
$u= \int_0^r \rho r^2 dr,  0 <= r <= r'\tag3$
$dv=- \frac{1}{r^2}dr,                 r'<= r <= \infty$
So we have:
$du =  \rho r^2 dr\tag5$
$\int_r^\infty (dv)=\int_r^\infty (- dr/r^2) \to v-v(\infty)=1/r$
where,
$v(\infty)=0\implies v=1/r$
Then replacing those in the main formula of $\int d(uv)=\int (vdu)+\int (udv)$
$1/r \int_0^r \rho r^2 dr = \int_?^? (1/r) ( \rho r^2 dr) +\int_\infty^r (\int_0^r \rho r^2 dr) (- dr/r^2)\tag6$
I guessed that the integral limits of first term on the right hand side might be $0$ ( the lower limit) and $r$ (as the upper limit) because limits of u function are those and we have $du$ in that integral. But my guess didn't match with Eq.(2). For the second term of Eq.(6), the limits of first integral, (infinity,r) are easy to understand because we have $dv$ and it is defined from infinity to r. Now it is my question how to find the limits of single integrals when we use integration by parts with variable limits?

What is $\rho$?

@user170231 It is density of mass.
